# Custom email subscription for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I make a **custom subscription form** for wordpress to get name and email from the users.
and it should send email to them when new posts published..?

Anyone know about this please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin?

> **Subscribe2**
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/
>  Sends a list
>   of subscribers an email notification when new posts are published to
>   your blog

Comment: Yes, the best one.. But there are no fields to get user name.. :( 
I have got another simple one from my friend. Trying to edit it now :)

Answer (score 0):

We just released a plugin that has an option for collecting name:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/postmatic/

> Postmatic lets your readers subscribe to comments or new posts by email. And leave a comment by simply hitting reply. No forms. No browsers. Email.

Comment: Unfortunately the above link now goes to a different plugin, Replyable. Postmatic is now a pay-for-subscription service.